# Async/ConfigureAwait(True) does not wait - WebService

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous, async-await

I have a webservice `GetCard` which calls a function `CreateRaces`. Inside the CreateRaces I am saving the new objects. This works fine without async. However, when I call the async function for `task1` `CommitAsync` the method executes and returns a response **without hitting the next break point**. I have tried to work around with via Task.Run, ConfigureWait(true), and with

```
With HttpContext.Current
  bulk.Setup etc...
End With
```

but nothing seems to work.

The `bulk.Setup` - `CommitAsync` calls a third party dll ([SqlBulkTools](https://github.com/olegil/SqlBulkTools)) which returns `Task`.

It looks like it works on a different thread.

Any ideas how to configure it so I the function executes and I can hit the next break point which is `sw.Stop()`?

```
 <HttpGet>
    <AllowAnonymous>
    Public Async Function GetCard(cardurl As String) As HttpResponseMessage
        Try
            Dim oRace As New RaceCard(cardurl)
            oRace.DoWork()
            Dim oRC As New RaceController
            await oRC.CreateRaces(oRace.Races) 

        Return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, True.ToJson)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex)
    End Try

End Function
```

CreateRaces function

```
Public Async Function CreateRaces(ByVal t As List(Of Race)) As Threading.Tasks.Task(Of Boolean)
    Try
        'Proceed only if list has items
        If t.Count > 0 Then
            Dim bulk As New BulkOperations()
            Dim sw As New Stopwatch()
            Dim oCon As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(DotNetNuke.Common.Utilities.Config.GetConnectionString)
            sw.Start()
            Dim task1 = Await bulk.Setup(Of Race).ForCollection(t).WithTable("ArbiRace").AddAllColumns().BulkInsertOrUpdate().SetIdentityColumn(Function(i) i.RaceID).MatchTargetOn(Function(m) m.RaceName).CommitAsync(oCon).ConfigureAwait(True)
            sw.Stop()
            Dim swt = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds
        End If

        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim s As String
        s = ex.ToString
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: `Await oRC.CreateRaces(oRace.Races)` and you should change signature of `GetCard` to be asynchronous too

Comment: @Fabio I have tried that now, same behaviour

Comment: Can you post the updated code?

Comment: @PauloMorgado done

Comment: If `CreateRaces` fails `GetCard` still returns an ok, Did you mean to `Throw` so the user gets the 500 from `GetCard`? Then examine what response you get back.

Comment: @JSteward no, the program is in debug mode and I'm trying to reach the breakpoint on sw.stop(). The breakpoint never hits

Comment: Does get into the `Catch` block where any and all Exceptions are being swallowed?

Comment: @JSteward no exceptions

Answer (score 0):

Asnyc calls can be handled in 2 ways:

1. Deliberately halting thread execution until one, several, or all tasks are completed.
2. Leaving the task to run while the current thread goes to do something else.

Based on your question, you are expecting #1, but your code currently does #2. [Await Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/await-operator):

> An Await expression or statement does not block the thread on which it is executing. Instead, it causes the compiler to sign up the rest of the async method, after the Await expression, as a continuation on the awaited task. Control then returns to the caller of the async method. When the task completes, it invokes its continuation, and execution of the async method resumes where it left off.

In your case, once CreateRaces() reaches the `Dim task1` line (which will eventually store the result, not the task), control returns to GetCard(). However, the CreateRaces() call here also uses an Await, so control attempts to go back up the call stack again. Except, there is nowhere left to go up, because you are at the original endpoint. This is why you seem to get a response too soon.

Since you are waiting for the task to finish to get the elapsed time, you want to wait for the tasks to finish before returning a response. This can be accomplished with task.Result, task.Wait(), or the shared method Task.WaitAll().

Example:

```
<HttpGet>
<AllowAnonymous>
Public Function GetCard(ByVal cardUrl As String) As HttpResponseMessage
    Try
        Dim oRace As New RaceCard(cardurl)
        oRace.DoWork()
        Dim oRC As New RaceController
        Dim createRacesTask As Threading.Tasks.Task(Of Boolean) = oRC.CreateRaces(oRace.Races)

        'Do other tasks here while we wait

        Threading.Tasks.Task.WaitAll(createRacesTask, ...)
        Return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, True.ToJson)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex)
    End Try
End Function
```